# Align instances along curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

Can't align instances along curve.
If i delete nodes marked with yellow, it works fine, but i need this result on points of mesh. How can i achieve this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

capture the curve tangent and use it as a vector input for the align euler to vector node

[image]

[image]